# Python POST Request Replication Receiving 403 Response

Tags: python, post, python-requests

Problem: Attempting to submit a POST request using python but I am receiving a `403` response instead of the desired `200` response.
 
Code using to perform the request:

```
import requests
import time
from datetime import datetime
 
 
URL = 'https://api.tools.pinpoll.com/v2/vote'
 
postheaders = {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Length": "65",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Host": "api.tools.pinpoll.com",
        "Origin": "https://tools.pinpoll.com",
        "Referer": "https://tools.pinpoll.com/",
        "sec-ch-ua": '"Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"}#    return postheaders
 
payload = {"poll_id": "1204091011", "answer_id": "4791050607", "require_user_opt_in": 'false'}
session = requests.Session()
 
response = session.post(URL, json=payload, headers=postheaders)
print(response.status_code)
```

This is the request that I am trying to replicate:

```
General:
Request URL: https://api.tools.pinpoll.com/v2/vote
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 40.113.142.219:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
 
Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://tools.pinpoll.com
Content-Length: 143
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 13 Apr 2021 21:35:45 GMT
ETag: W/"8f-aq+f2/q1qOlfyP7DIoENL7USUPk"
Set-Cookie: visitor=eyJpdiI6ImpYTlFvQzJCWmtUWmNZL09XeWk3T2c9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjVkZDMwMDBmZjU4MTc5MmQwODFhNGIyMWQwYmM3ODIwZmExNTM4ZTliMDU1ZGFlODZhZDA5YzIyYjUxNjA3ZWYiLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ii84RU1PeXM4QWU5T1VuaE9oQ3ZKQ0E9PSJ9; Max-Age=2592000; Domain=pinpoll.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 13 May 2021 21:35:46 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
X-Powered-By: Express
 
Request Headers:
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 65
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host: api.tools.pinpoll.com
Origin: https://tools.pinpoll.com
Referer: https://tools.pinpoll.com/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36
 
Request Payload:
{poll_id: 1204091011, answer_id: 4791050607, require_user_opt_in: false}
answer_id: 4791050607
poll_id: 1204091011
require_user_opt_in: false
```

Desired outcome:
I would like to be able to replicate this request and receive the `200` response.

Comment: how did you get this request data? If you use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or similar then it should have function to generate code in `Python`. If you get it from Chrome/Firefox then it should have option to generate code in `curl` which you can try to convert to `Python` on https://curl.trillworks.com

Comment: if you use `json=` then you don't have set header `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` because it will set it automatically. And it will count correct length for JSON data.

Comment: you could add URL where you get it. Maybe it uses something more to block it - especially if it is not official API.

Comment: you should also check `response.text` - maybe there is some useful info. When I run your code then I get error `404` and `{"status":"error","data":{"message":"embedsettings for poll 1204091011 not found","code":"not_found"}}`

Comment: @furas Thank you! I haven't used curl.trillworks.com previously but that did the trick. I am still looking through the code to see what exactly I wrote incorrectly and will post when I do.